# Celery should return a non-zero exit code an exception occurs

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm experiencing a weird situation with **Celery 4.1**, Python 2.7.13. When there is an issue with the connection between Python app and Database (MySQL in this case), Celery does not return a non-zero code and keep the worker running which doesn't make any sense.

Although I can see the exception in the result of `celery -A myapp worker -l INFO -E` but the worker doesn't stop. I tried almost all options of `celery` worker but no luck.

Is there any way to force the worker to stop working and exit if the database connection is failing?